# Convert a string (which is a valid object structure, however not a valid json structure) into an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following string is embedded within the page of my site as the value of a hidden input. If I retrieve it how can I turn it into an actual object?

```
{id: '151901', name: 'Whisper Boots', image: '/wcsstore7.00.00.550/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/products/large/WHISPS.jpg', type: 'ProductBean', components: {}, skus: [{id: '151902', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151903', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151904', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151905', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151906', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151907', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151908', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151909', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151910', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151911', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151912', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151924', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151925', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151926', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151927', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151928', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151929', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151930', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151931', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151932', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151933', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151934', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151935', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151936', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151937', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151938', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151939', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151940', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151941', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151942', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151943', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151944', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151945', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151957', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151958', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151959', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151960', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151961', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151962', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151963', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151964', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151965', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151966', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151967', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214002', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214015', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214016', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214017', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214018', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214019', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214020', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214021', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214022', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214023', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214024', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214025', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214026', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214027', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214040', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214041', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214042', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214043', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214044', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214045', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214046', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214047', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214048', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214049', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214050', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214051', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214064', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214065', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214066', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214067', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214068', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214069', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214070', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214071', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214072', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214073', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214074', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214075', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275608', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275609', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275610', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275611', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275612', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275613', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275614', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275615', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275616', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275617', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275618', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275619', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275620', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275621', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275622', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275623', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275624', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275625', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275626', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275627', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275628', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275629', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275630', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275631', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275632', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275633', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}}]}
```

I tried using `jQuery.parseJSON()` but because it's not valid JSON it doesn't work:

```
console.log( jQuery.parseJSON( $('#catEntryParams').val()) );
```

Returns the following error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1
```

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourvalue))` ?

Comment: Is it required to send invalid JSON?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja it's a string, stringifying first is nonsensical.

Comment: This is already a json object

Comment: @Satpal - It's the value of a hidden input. Since inputs don't hold objects, it's a string.

Comment: @geoffs3310 can you share the error that it throws on `$.parseJOSN()`

Comment: @Satpal it's a value of an HTML element. It's a string.

Comment: `var myObject = JSON.parse($("#myHiddenInput").val());`

Comment: @vlaz Before parse it's better to stringify the value.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja IT IS A STRING ALREADY!

Comment: @geoffs3310 use regex to add quote `"` to propery name than use `JSON.parse` ? maybe.

Comment: You already have some server-side serialization code just to print the JavaScript object literal, it should be trivial to tweak it and produce any other format (JSON, XML... you name it). Of course, we all know how some companies work and I wouldn't be surprised that the most expensive workaround gets chosen.

Answer (score 5):

You already know that your string is **not** a valid JSON format, I really recommend you to send a valid JSON string, however if you really can't there is the option of using the `eval()` function here.

I know the eval is the root of all evil, however sometimes you don't really have a choice.

## KEEP IN MIND!

> The usage of eval is dangerous and can open your code to malicious injections! The solution here should be changing the original source and make sure the string is a valid json (and use `JSON.parse`, and **not** the eval).

If you really must use the `eval` - here is an example:

```js
s = "{id: '151901', name: 'Whisper Boots', image: '/wcsstore7.00.00.550/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/products/large/WHISPS.jpg', type: 'ProductBean', components: {}, skus: [{id: '151902', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151903', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151904', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151905', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151906', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151907', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151908', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151909', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151910', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151911', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151912', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151924', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151925', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151926', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151927', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151928', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151929', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151930', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151931', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151932', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151933', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151934', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151935', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151936', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151937', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151938', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151939', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151940', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151941', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151942', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151943', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151944', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151945', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151957', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151958', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151959', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151960', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151961', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151962', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151963', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151964', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151965', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151966', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151967', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214002', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214015', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214016', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214017', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214018', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214019', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214020', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214021', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214022', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214023', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214024', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214025', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214026', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214027', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214040', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214041', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214042', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214043', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214044', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214045', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214046', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214047', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214048', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214049', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214050', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214051', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214064', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214065', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214066', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214067', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214068', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214069', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214070', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214071', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214072', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214073', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214074', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214075', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275608', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275609', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275610', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275611', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275612', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275613', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275614', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275615', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275616', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275617', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275618', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275619', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275620', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275621', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275622', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275623', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275624', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275625', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275626', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275627', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275628', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275629', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275630', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275631', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275632', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275633', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}}]}"
eval('s = ' + s);alert("You really shouldn't use the `eval` function unless you know what you do! Read the entire post before copy-paste.");
console.log(s.id)
```

Comment: The post itself says that this value is extracted from an embedded field on the page - this means that an evil user could essentially execute whatever JS code he desires! `eval` has it's uses - but I wouldn't recommend using it on user supplied input unless it is HEAVILY sanitized.

Comment: @Lix An evil user can just type whatever JavaScript code he wants in the console, he doesn't have to inject it first in HTML.

Comment: I gotta downvote this, @dekel - sorry friend. While this might solve the OP's current issue I fear it'll introduce a much much larger one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález unless the code is injected in _somebody else's_ browser, then the evil user has successfully taken control of everything an innocent user is doing.#

Comment: What scenario do you have in mind where you can inject random HTML in somebody else's browser but not random JavaScript code?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - without any context on what exactly is going to be done with this code I tend to assume the worst... "It's not paranoia if people are actually out to get you" ;)

Comment: the correct answer is "don't store javascript objects in an input." op could just as easily put the jso in a script tag. this doesn't justify using eval.

Comment: Best answer is "I really recommend you to send a valid JSON string" and, you know, it's already here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that string gets _somehow_ into the page. If the attacker can manipulate that, then you have your code injection vulnerability. One of the things in that object is image location - if that is changed, to, say a script that loads up, steals all your cookies, places a bunch of stuff in your cart and presses "Buy", that `eval` will blindly execute it.

Comment: @Lix, I agree that you really shouldn't use the `eval` function (unless you **must**), but in this case the only other option is to try and parse the code yourself and rebuild the string as a valid json string (which isn't that easy...)

Comment: vlas' point is valid. while anyone can add code in the console, most pages js is secured in it's own scope in a `$(function(){})` or similar and is not accessible via the console. when it's in an input it's global and easily changed.

Comment: @Dekel - what actually needs to happen here is to get to the bottom of where this string is coming from and asses the possibility of sending a valid JSON object. Then establishing exactly what is going to be done with this evaled code and probably a bunch of other questions that don't come to mind right now. I honestly feel that suggesting eval without all of this surrounding context is a bad idea... But hey - this is what the voting system is for - looks like the majority of viewers (currently) agree with you.

Comment: I agree that the user should understand the risks here, this is why I wrote that you really should use a valid json and **not** use the eval in this case. I'll update the answer with a better warning, hope it will make people more "forgiveness" about the usage of the eval in this case :)

Comment: @Dekel - agreed. A more substantial warning is needed IMO. However having the code sample right there...so...copy pasteable... :P I can assure you that many won't heed your warnings when their 'solution' is just a `Ctrl+c` away.

Comment: I'll add a fix for that too. Wait a sec ;-)

Comment: @Dekel - BIGGER! BOLDER! hehe... One step further - put your code sample as a picture of text. It's ridiculous - yes. But I think it's a great way to pretty much say "don't actually use this". But yea - better :)

Comment: hehe :) I guess I'll only get your downvote removed, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that however that when the information is being put in the HTML tag, it's not formatted as valid JSON. The [`eval` solution by Dekel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401387/3689450) would work but it is also vulnerable.

A "patch" that will allow you to load the data *as* JSON and do it more securely is to format the string.

```js
var input = $("#specialInput").val()

var jsonifiedInput = input.replace(/'/g, '"') // replace single quotes with double quotes
  .replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":'); // wrap all keys into double quotes.

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonifiedInput);

console.log("--TYPE:", typeof obj);
console.log(jsonifiedInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="specialInput" value="{id: '151901', name: 'Whisper Boots', image: '/wcsstore7.00.00.550/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/images/products/large/WHISPS.jpg', type: 'ProductBean', components: {}, skus: [{id: '151902', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151903', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151904', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151905', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151906', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151907', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151908', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151909', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151910', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151911', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151912', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151924', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151925', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151926', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151927', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151928', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151929', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151930', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151931', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151932', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151933', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151934', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151935', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151936', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151937', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151938', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151939', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151940', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151941', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151942', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151943', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151944', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151945', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '151957', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '151958', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '151959', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '151960', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '151961', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '151962', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '151963', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '151964', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '151965', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '151966', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '151967', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214002', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214015', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214016', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214017', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214018', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214019', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214020', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214021', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214022', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214023', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214024', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214025', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214026', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214027', attributes: {'Colour': 'Black','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214040', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214041', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214042', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214043', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214044', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214045', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214046', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214047', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214048', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214049', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214050', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214051', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '214064', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '214065', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '214066', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '214067', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '214068', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '214069', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '214070', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '214071', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '214072', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '214073', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '214074', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '214075', attributes: {'Colour': 'Plum','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275608', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275609', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275610', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275611', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275612', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275613', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275614', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275615', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275616', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275617', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275618', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275619', attributes: {'Colour': 'Deep Teal','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275620', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Extra Wide Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275621', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3'}},{id: '275622', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}},{id: '275623', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4'}},{id: '275624', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '4.5'}},{id: '275625', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5'}},{id: '275626', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '5.5'}},{id: '275627', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6'}},{id: '275628', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '6.5'}},{id: '275629', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7'}},{id: '275630', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '7.5'}},{id: '275631', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '8'}},{id: '275632', attributes: {'Colour': 'Gunmetal','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '9'}},{id: '275633', attributes: {'Colour': 'Navy','Fit': 'Standard Fit','Size': '3.5'}}]}" />
```

**NOTE:** this is still meant as a workaround that is more secure than using `eval`. I would still strongly suggest you fix the underlying issue and receive the data as proper JSON.

The problem is that it relies on string parsing and automated replacement in order to form valid JSON.

**Replacing `'` (single quote) with `"` (double quite)** - works *in this case* because all values (and some keys) are wrapped in single quotes. However if you had a value of, say `"Resse's pieces"` (serialised with an escaped quote) or `'M&M\'s'` (serialised with double quotes) then replacing blindly would fail.

**Wrapping keys in double quotes** - works if the key is alphanumeric - a key of `Coca-cola:` will be replaced with `Coca-"Cola":` among other problems.

Again, this is a *temporary* solution and is going to work for *this* dataset. It could be extended for others, but the main problem should be treated.

Comment: Nice solution! +1 from me here :) note that it will not work if you have asd: inside the values (and might be some other problematic characters also... didn't do a complete check).

Comment: @Dekel indeed `asd:` inside won't work but it's really, really, hard to account for everything, so I kept it to the simplest case. If you try to check "comma, space, word characters, semicolon` then that might still show up as a value. If you try something more complex, it could still be a problem. You know the old saying `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`, hence why this isn't a "real" solution but intended as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I agree :) just wanted to mention this issue here (and you got +1 from me anyway ;) )

Comment: @Dekel fair enough, I'll add it to the answer to be more explicit.